# PHP -- Issue With Sticky Radio Buttons

Tags: php, html

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm having an issue. I have a function which generates radio buttons based on the number of values on a table in a database. The only fields on these tables are value and property. This function is called on another page, and the problem I'm having is I want whichever button is selected to be sticky.

```
function buildRadio($table)
{

    if (!isset($_SESSION['create_profile'][$table]))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $result = pg_query(db_connect(), $sql);
        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="'. "$table" .'" value="'.$row['value'].'" />'.$row['property'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $temp = $_SESSION['create_profile'][$table];            
        echo "<input type='radio' name='$table' value='$temp' checked='checked'>";
    }
}
```

What's in the else block is my attempt at trying to identify which button the user has selected based on the session info, and reload the page with that button being sticky. All it does it right now is create one checked button. I'm not entirely sure how I should proceed from here to achieve this, and was wondering if someone could give me a bit of insight.

Comment: What you do mean by sticky ?

Comment: I assume he means: keeping it checked after a page reload.

Comment: Yes. What needs to happen if when the user selects a radio button and the form is reloaded, that radio button remains selected.

Comment: If you use AJAX, it's like everything is sticky. Otherwise, you test for the `isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])` or `isset($_GET['checkbox_name'])` altering the HTML checked attribute to `checked='checked'`. Really, AJAX is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the button to not reset after a page update/reload. I would use localStorage in Javascript. Definetly not send a Ajax request to the server for each button clicked.

After all this is client side related, and keeping track of progress or working with remembering temporary choices should definetly be restricted to the client side.

What if the client wants to reset their selection, but you have stored it in say `$_SESSION`. That would be a pain to delete their cookies, having to login again in stead of just clearing their local storage.

Edit: Your echo line looks bad. It should be:
`echo '<input type="radio" name="', $table, '" value="', $row['value'], '" />', $row['property'];`
It is alright to use dots. I'm just old school (I guess).

Comment: That's a bit beyond me. This is for my 2nd Web Development class. Thanks for the suggestion though, especially the edit.

Comment: It is actually simpler than setting up a PHP solution. So I highly suggest using localStorage to keep track of which radio buttons have been checked. I would even go as far as saying it is the proper way to handle it due to my previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can't escape array variables with single quotes and then use single quotes within the array